# tmux blocks certain things on my Mac

Tags: terminal, x11, osx, tmux

I really like `tmux` and use it often so I set the following in my `.zprofile`:

```
[[ $TERM != "screen" ]] && exec tmux
```

so when I open a new window, `tmux` will be there for me.

However, there are some strange things that happen when `tmux` is running:

- `gnuplot`, `octave` and other programs that need to launch X11 to draw graphs
  can't seem to do so (or it takes *really* long - 10 minutes or so). When X11
  is already running, they don't have this problem though.
- Some scripts I write use `osascript` to alert me with a notification when something happens:

  ```
  osascript -e 'display notification "some text" with title "Foo"'
  ```

  this works fine when `tmux` is not active, but fails to do anything when called from within a `tmux` session. (note that other `osascript` actions *do* work)

Does anyone have an idea why this might be and what might be done to fix this?

**Note:** I've posted a [similar question about the first problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127427/xquartz-is-not-starting-from-within-tmux) on the apple.se site
some time ago but got no answer. The second problem only sprung up recently so I thought I'd try my luck here.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving `[[ $TERM != "screen" ]] && exec tmux` to your `.zshrc` file. That way the command will only be run in interactive shells.

An interactive shell is simply any shell process that you use to type commands, and get back output from those commands. That is, a shell with which you interact.

Comment: Aha! This works for the `gnuplot` problem! But not for the `display notifications` problem though. Any thoughts on that? If you want, please post this answer to [my similar question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127427/xquartz-is-not-starting-from-within-tmux), since it would be totally correct there!

Answer (score 2):

Your second problem seems to be an issue with tmux and the evaluation of certain AppleScripts through `osascript`. There's a wrapper you can install which should fix the problem.

You'll want to install [reattach-to-user-namespace](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) through Homebrew or MacPorts and wrap the call to `osascript`:

```
reattach-to-user-namespace osascript  -e 'display notification "Hello, world"'
```